# Footer styling not being applied for footer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a footer to my page exactly as they do [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_footer). I am using a div with the same class defined for it but it still will not show the footer at the bottom. What am I missing here. Thank you. Full code at [this](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/PoNXByd?editors=1100) codepen.

```css
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

Comment: works fine for me in this snippet. There is nothing wrong. to pin down the error, you should include all of your code.

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via the code snippet function.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't see any footer in your ``codepen.io`` link and if what I see their is a footer then its quite unique. Your code is not clean pls provide minimal reproducible example via code snippet here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing your CSS styling right before:

```
$custom-file-text: (
    en: "Browse",
    es: "Elegir"
);
```

seems to achieve the desired effect. See [here](https://codepen.io/GeneralPoxter/pen/gOMmbZp).